# com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: reason: not a sub-string

Tags: karate

I use Karate framework V 0.7.0 to perform some automatic API tests.

I've got one test inside the following scenario that return an exception com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: reason: **not a sub-string**

Here is the following scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: Put a number, and check the JSON response body.

Given path '/number/check/'
And param serial = '<number>'
When method GET
Then status 200
And match $ contains {"uid":"#uuid","reference":"#notnull","type":"#notnull","name":"#notnull","description":"#notnull","imageUrl":"#notnull","color":"<color>","reason":"<reason>"}

Examples:

  | number | color | reason |
  # Case 1
  |  1234 | RED   | INITIAL_WARRANTY_EXPIRED                  |
  # Case 2
  |  5678 | RED   | INELIGIBLE_PRODUCT_FAMILY                 |
  # Case 3
  |  9012 | RED   | ALREADY_EXTENDED                          |
```

**Case 1 and 2 pass correctly.**

**Case 3 return the following:**

```
StackTrace:
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: path: $, actual: '[{"uid":"2cd897fd-1421-4c02-b594-6ee0de38db3d","reference":"a random reference","type":"a random type","name":"a random name","description":"a random description","imageUrl":"a random image url","color":"RED","reason":"ALREADY_EXTENDED"}]', expected: '{"uid":"#uuid","reference":"#notnull","type":"#notnull","name":"#notnull","description":"#notnull","imageUrl":"#notnull","color":"RED","reason":"ALREADY_EXTENDED"}', reason: not a sub-string

at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchNamed(StepDefs.java:540)

at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchContains(StepDefs.java:532)

at ✽.And match $ contains {"uid":"#uuid","reference":"#notnull","type":"#notnull","name":"#notnull","description":"#notnull","imageUrl":"#notnull","color":"RED","reason":"ALREADY_EXTENDED"}
```

I've checked **manually**, this is the **JSON answer** for the Case 3:

```
[{"uid":"2cd897fd-1421-4c02-b594-6ee0de38db3d","reference":"a random reference","type":"a random type","name":"a random name","description":"a random description","imageUrl":"a random image url","color":"RED","reason":"ALREADY_EXTENDED"}]
```

I don't understand why **only** the Case 3 failed.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Edit 1: ""reference" is a wrong copy paste. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:

After investigation, the exact same test runs well when launched by **JUnit**, but not by using **Maven**. It was a problem with encoding.

**Solution**: force the encoding in the Surefire plugin by using:

```
<argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
```

in the pom.xml like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>api/TestParallel.java</include>
        </includes>
        <systemProperties>
             <cucumber.options>--tags ~@ignore</cucumber.options>
        </systemProperties>
        <argLine>${argLine} -Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding}</argLine>
     <configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Documentation here:** https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master#troubleshooting-cucumber-ide-support -> file.encoding.

**Important note:**
if you run your test in parallel, and you switch environments by using:

```
mvn clean test -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=YOUR_ENV"
```

it's important to use the syntax...

```
<argLine>${argLine} -Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding}</argLine>
```

...instead of just...

```
<argLine>-Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding}</argLine>
```

otherwise, the Maven -DargLine will be **overwritten** by the one in your POM.xml.

Comment: great ! upvoted :) thanks for the details, this will surely help others.